# Twitter advanced search by date AND location for research purposes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter, screen-scraping

I'm trying to research a topic and I need to get all tweets within 2013 and 2015 and a specific location for two keywords.

I tried to get the results via Advanced Search but I allways get no results.

I tried:

```
cannabis near:"España" within:15mi since:2013-10-07 until:2015-01-01
cannabis near:"Spain" within:15mi since:2013-10-07 until:2015-01-01
```

Basically, I have a database of scraped press articles sorted by date from a bunch of sources, and I want to know how the agenda of this news sources have an impact on the social media conversation.

I could do it over Reddit if it was the case for the US, but there's no Spanish alternative (well, we have Meneame, but the user base is very left-leaning and I think it will be very narrow).

So I wanted to either scrape the search results or get them via API, but It's not working, and AFAIK I can't do anything similar with Facebook.

Comment: What code have you tried? What documentation did you use? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Well, I used no code, just the advanced search. I have an app (seotools for excel) with the ability to retrieve via API and it also shows the same when combining operators: nothing.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by using Twitter's geocode operator. In the example below i took Madrid as a center and covered a radius of 600km around it like this:

```
(canabis OR cannabis) geocode:40.4381311,-3.8196196,600km since:2013-10-07 until:2015-12-31
```

[Try it...](https://twitter.com/search?q=%20(canabis%20OR%20cannabis)%20geocode%3A40.4381311%2C-3.8196196%2C600km%20since%3A2013-10-07%20until%3A2015-12-31&src=typed_query&f=live)

The syntax is as follows:

```
([your_boolean_search_query]) geocode:[latitude],[longitude],[radius]km since:[] until:[]
```

one easy way to find latitudes and longitudes of locations is to use Google Maps. Simply navigate to a place using the search box and then copy the `latitude` and `longitude` element from the URL line in the browser. Here it is for Madrid. The `latitude` and `longitude` are right after the `@` sign, separated by a comma:

`https://www.google.com/maps/place/Madrid,+Spain/@`**`40.4381311,-3.8196196`**`,54451m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd422997800a3c81:0xc436dec1618c2269!8m2!3d40.4167754!4d-3.7037902?hl=en`

[Try it...](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Madrid,+Spain/@40.4381311,-3.8196196,54451m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0xd422997800a3c81:0xc436dec1618c2269!8m2!3d40.4167754!4d-3.7037902?hl=en)